# Let $k_i = \{x \in \mathbb N, m\in \mathbb N: x=im\}$ for $i \in \mathbb N$ and $i>1$. Is the $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} k_i$ empty?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, examples-counterexamples

I want to give a counter example to the statement saying that:

Given a collection of closed (not necessarily bounded) sets where the finite intersection of any of these sets is nonempty, the infinite intersection is also nonempty.

The counter example is:

$k_i = \{x \in \mathbb N, m\in \mathbb N: x=im\}$ for $i \in \mathbb N$ and $i>1$.

For $i=2$, $k_2 = \{2,4,6,...\}$.

For $i=3$, $k_3 = \{3,6,9,...\}$.

.....

There may exist other examples to show this, but this came to my mind and I want to see if it works.

I don't know number theory yet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no number that is a multiple of every integer. For example, $n$ can not be a multiple of $n+1$.

Comment: ..which is easier, good job.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works. But $m$ belongs to $k_1,\ldots,k_n$ then all the primes $p_1,\ldots,p_r \le n$ divides $m$. In particular, $m\ge p_1\cdots p_r$. But $r$ is not finite hence such $m$ cannot exist.

Comment: Would it not be nicer if I changed the $k_i$ definition to be multiples of the $m^{th}$ prime? It would be like $k_5$ has all the multiples of 5, and $k_7$ has multiple of 7, and their infinite intersection must be empty because otherwise would imply the primes are finite correct?